# I can't get LongClick to work on ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, long-click

I have already asked this, but didn't get an solution that works and I have since amedned the code.

Can anyone help me and advise why my Long Click function is not working please?:

```
public class InspectionActivity extends ListActivity {
private Button newInspection;
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;

private RMDbAdapter rmDbHelper;
//private AlertDialog longClickOptionsDialog;
private AlertDialog clickOptionsDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspection);
    setUpViews();
    rmDbHelper = new RMDbAdapter(this);
    rmDbHelper.open();

    // Get a Cursor for the list items
    Cursor listCursor = rmDbHelper.fetchAllInspections();
    startManagingCursor(listCursor);           

    // set the custom list adapter     
    setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));

}

private void setUpViews() {
    newInspection = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_inspection);
    newInspection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                       
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createInspection();
        }
    }); 

}

// In your ListActivity class, create a new inner class that extends ResourceCursorAdapter. 
//This inner class is the custom CursorAdapter we will use to manage how data is bound to a list item:

private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter { 

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        super(context, R.layout.inspection_row, cursor);

    } 

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inspection_row_item_main_title);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(                            
                cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)));

        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inspection_row_item_description);        

        String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "Company unknown");
        String inspectionDate = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_DATE)), "date unknown");
        description.setText("(" + companyName + ", " + inspectionDate + ")");   
    } 
}


private void createInspection() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, InspectionEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int pos, final long id){


    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchInspection(id);

    String inspectionRef = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)), "Reference unknown"); 
    String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "company unknown"); 
    final String inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")"; 

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
    clickOptionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InspectionActivity.this)
    .setTitle(inspectionDialogueText)
    .setMessage(R.string.general_text_select_option)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.general_button_open, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(InspectionActivity.this, AreaActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("intentID", id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            }
        })
    .setNeutralButton(R.string.general_button_edit, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            Intent i = new Intent(InspectionActivity.this, InspectionEdit.class);
            i.putExtra("intentID", id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            }
        })

    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            clickOptionsDialog.cancel();
            }
        })
    .create();
    clickOptionsDialog.show();

}

protected void onListItemLongClick(ListView l, View v, final int pos, final long id){

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchInspection(id);

    String inspectionRef = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_REF)), "Reference unknown"); 
    String companyName = RMUtilities.notEmpty(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
            RMDbAdapter.INSPECTION_COMPANY)), "company unknown"); 
    final String inspectionDialogueText = "(" + inspectionRef + ", " + companyName + ")"; 

    clickOptionsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InspectionActivity.this)
    .setTitle(inspectionDialogueText)
    .setMessage(R.string.general_text_select_option)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.general_button_open, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(InspectionActivity.this, AreaActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("intentID", id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            }
        })
    .setNeutralButton(R.string.general_button_edit, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            Intent i = new Intent(InspectionActivity.this, InspectionEdit.class);
            i.putExtra("intentID", id);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
            }
        })

    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            clickOptionsDialog.cancel();
            }
        })
    .create();
    clickOptionsDialog.show();
}
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not override the `onListItemLongClick` because its not a member of ListActivity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

You have to set the OnItemLongClickListener as followed:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int row, long arg3) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi lon Aalbers - that's great thanks, but where do I put this in my code as I seem to get errors whereever I put it..

Comment: @Scamparelli Can you not put it in onCreate?

Comment: I have got this error: The method setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemLongClickListener(){}), what now?

Comment: @AJeneral Try : new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {}

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
newInspection.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {             
        return true;         
     }
 });
```

Comment: This is valid for a long click on a normal view, not for an item in the listview.