# Long click to begin selecting items in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, long-click

My question is simple: How do I use long click to let the users select items from the `ListView` ? So far, I only know how to detect 'short' clicks and take appropriate actions.

Also, I would like to display a check mark on the selected item. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple : [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Then you need to manually remember what is selected or not. You need to notify the list from the changes and do something in the getView method of you adapter.

It would be a good practice to use the Contextual ActionBar mode to interact with all item at once, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

Comment: I am not talking about simply displaying a context menu rather selecting items in bulk

Answer (score 2):

Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090394/i-cant-get-longclick-to-work-on-listactivity :

```
// Optional, added if done from ListActivity (or possibly ListFragment)
ListView lv = getListView();
// Set on this if overriding OnItemLongClickListener, otherwise use an anonymous inner function
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

It works the same way as the `onClickListener`, just instead you're checking the `onLongClickListener`. So you'd have this kind of structure:

```
your_view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    ...
  }
});
```

If you want to display a check mark, in my opinion the best way is defining your own row layout, where you just define a `CheckBox` at the right side the content of the row. This way, instead of passing the `ArrayAdapter` some Android layout, you'd specify your new layout, something like:

```
your_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.your_new_layout, initial_rows);
```

Comment: If in my layout if I keep a check box with visibility `GONE`, and display it on long click, will it work ?

Comment: You need to call notifyDataSetChanged on you adapter, then the getView method will be called for every visible row, you can then do everything you can like displaying a checkbox, change the background color, etc.

Comment: Sure, simply declare the `onLongClickListener` inside your overriden `getView()` method. The second parameter of that method (usually called `convertView`) is (talking very vaguely) the layout of every row. You could simply get the `CheckBox`'s view by using `convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox)`, and afterwards you can do anything you want, set its visibility VISIBLE, GONE...

Comment: @NKN yeah, I get the gist . And Thank you Stephane for the addition  =) However, remembering what is selected will be manual task, right ?

Comment: Yes, a list of integer is enough, just save the row number.